# How can I change the starting location of Internet Explorer's Open File dialog?

Tags: internet-explorer

I usually use Firefox, but once in a while I fire up IE9 for an unusual file type or a site that doesn't play nice with NoScript. When I go to `File > Open...`, and then click `Browse...`, IE automatically starts me off in the last folder I opened something from. That's usually not helpful for me. How can I set it to start in the same folder every time?